# FirebaseのCloud Firestoreのドキュメントが更新されない

Tags: swift, firebase

プログラムコードでFirestoreへの更新にユーザIDと画像をBase64でエンコードした文字列をドキュメント追加したいのですがFirestoreのコンソール画面に新しく追加したものが表示されません。
プログラムコードで追加されたデータを取得することはできるのですがコンソール画面に表示されません。
＊ユーザIDのみでドキュメントを作成するとできます

エンコードされた文字列が長すぎて表示されることができないのか単純にFireStoreのコンソールのバグなのか原因不利なの状態です。

わかる方がいらっしゃれば、ご教授願いします。

Comment: Firestoreに大きい容量のデータを入れたことがないので推測ですが、SDKを通じてデータが取得できるならコンソール側になにか問題が起きてそうですね。 解決するかはわかりませんがサポートへ問い合わせてみるのがよさそうです。 https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速問い合わせてみたいと思います。